# Where is bootstrap/autoload.php in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel-5

In previous versions of `Laravel` there was a file `autoload.php`. After I installed `Laravel 5.5`, that file is not found. Is it moved or deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like in all composer projects: `vendor\autoload.php`

Comment: This seems odd to me because the vendor\autoload.php file can get auto generated by composer. Which is why I don't choose not to store the entire vendor folder in SCM. But yet, I want to make customizations to it (like add my own required .php to be loaded on startup). This was easier in autoload.php, which was a file I could keep around in the bootstrap folder. For example, https://blackfyre.ninja/blog/fixing-slug-generation-problems

Answer (score 0):

This file was removed in this commit :

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/8914be5fc864ebc6877be38ff3502997e0c62761

he is now in `vendor/autoload.php`